# Can I create a macro that unrolls loops?

Tags: macros, rust

I'm trying to write some fast matrix code in Rust and to do this needs to ensure that loops are unrolled. Is there a way to create a compile-time for-loop? E.g: I want

```
unroll_loop!(f, a, 3);
```

to generate

```
f(a, 0);
f(a, 1);
f(a, 2);
```

Comment: I think you can write a syntax extension for this but regular `macro_rules`-macros won't help you because they do not have any kinds of variables or numbers available to them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, *sort of*.

```rust
macro_rules! unroll {
    (0, |$i:ident| $s:stmt) => {};
    (1, |$i:ident| $s:stmt) => {{ let $i: usize = 0; $s; }};
    (2, |$i:ident| $s:stmt) => {{ unroll!(1, |$i| $s); let $i: usize = 1; $s; }};
    (3, |$i:ident| $s:stmt) => {{ unroll!(2, |$i| $s); let $i: usize = 2; $s; }};
    (4, |$i:ident| $s:stmt) => {{ unroll!(3, |$i| $s); let $i: usize = 3; $s; }};
    // ...
}

fn main() {
    unroll!(3, |i| println!("i: {}", i));
}
```

You might be tempted to ask "why don't you just use `unroll!($i-1, |$i| $s)` for the recursive case?".  This is because *macros cannot do math*.  In fact, they cannot do *any* form of evaluation *whatsoever*.  You are basically limited to symbolic manipulation.

Macros also *cannot* interact with types or values in any way, which means the following **does not work, and cannot be made to work**:

```
const N: usize = 3;
unroll!(N, |i| println!("i: {}", i));
```

So, you *can* do this, but only for literal integers, and you have to write an explicit case in the macro for every integer to want to be able to use.

Comment: Just for those unaware to Rust's compiler plugins: One possible solution to this that works with arbitrary (yet compile-time known) numbers would be to implement a compiler plugin exposing an `unroll!(…)` macro with the same semantics. Plugins are not stable yet, though.